# Magento product custom options, show discount in cart

Tags: magento

i have a problem with my magento cms. On some of my products, i have added a custom option, with a dropdown. All the options in the dropdown gives 20% discount, and the discount is reduced from the price in the shopping cart, but i want the discount showed in the cart, like it does when a coupon is used. How can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to start using configurable products to adjust prices on options. You can easily solve this issue if you use configurable products and know some Magento programming.